Insertion of large rows in oracle 8i
we have a requirement for inserting large rows around 250,000-500,000 in a table using Oracle 8i.There are 3 columns each having 3 chars only. I wrote a simple shell script and so we had a local Oracle 19c DB which does the insertion in around 1 to 2 mins.(using Sql*Loader is not an option for us)
Now issue is that the actual DB where I need to insert is having oracle 8i. I am using the very same script. It is taking a lot of time to even insert 10000 records. I see with the present speed the same process will take around 8 hours. What is going wrong? How can I optimise it. It will be helpful to know if the version of Oracle is responsible or someting else.I have tried using batch insert with diff size like 200,500,1000 etc but no help. Does batch insert not help in Oracle 8i? Infact batch insert made it considerably faster for 19c.
Edit: I am adding the shell script I am using which takes just half second for insertion of 1000 records in 19c but same script takes minutes for that and so hours for actual records. So I am fetching records from db1 and inserting it to db2. Also the purpose of TEMP_SQL_FILE is to collect 1000 insert commands as a String in a file. BATCH_SIZE=50 helps me to collect 50 such inserts String which is put into the file. So ultimately, 1000
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (USERID, SALARY, ZIP) VALUES ('$USERID', '$SALARY', '$ZIPCODE');  will be collected in the temp file which is then inserted via sql plus.
#!/bin/ksh

# DB1 (source database) details (**19c**)
DB1_USER="user1"
DB1_PASSWORD="pwd1"
DB1_DB=db1.abc.com

# DB2 (destination database) connection details (**8i**)
DB2_USER="user2"
DB2_PASSWORD="pwd2"
DB2_DB=db2.xyz.com

# Temporary file to hold SQL commands
TEMP_SQL_FILE="batch_inserts.sql"
BATCH_SIZE=50  # Number of records to accumulate before writing to file
COMMIT_THRESHOLD=1000  # Number of records after which to commit
counter=0  # To keep track of total records written
batch_counter=0  # To track batch size
sql_batch=""

# SQL Query to fetch data from DB1 table1 table
SQL_QUERY="SELECT userid || '|' || salary || '|' || zip FROM table1;"

# Fetch data from DB1 and insert into DB2
sqlplus -s "$DB1_USER/$DB1_PASSWORD@$DB1_DB" <<EOF | while IFS='|' read -r USERID SALARY ZIPCODE
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 1000
$SQL_QUERY
EXIT;
EOF

do
    # Accumulate SQL insert statements in the batch variable
    sql_batch+="INSERT INTO TABLE2 (USERID, SALARY, ZIP) VALUES ('$USERID', '$SALARY', '$ZIPCODE');\n"
    ((batch_counter++))
    ((counter++))

    # Check if we reached the batch size, then write to file
    if [ "$batch_counter" -ge "$BATCH_SIZE" ]; then
        echo -e "$sql_batch" >> "$TEMP_SQL_FILE"
        sql_batch=""  # Clear the batch variable
        batch_counter=0  # Reset the batch counter
    fi

    # Check if we reached the commit threshold
    if [ "$counter" -ge "$COMMIT_THRESHOLD" ]; then
        # Execute the SQL batch
        sqlplus -s "$DB2_USER/$DB2_PASSWORD@$DB2_DB" <<EOF
        @$TEMP_SQL_FILE
        COMMIT;
        EXIT;
EOF
        # Clear the temporary file after commit
        > "$TEMP_SQL_FILE"
        counter=0  # Reset the counter after commit
    fi
done

# Final commit for any remaining records
if [ -n "$sql_batch" ]; then
    echo -e "$sql_batch" >> "$TEMP_SQL_FILE"
fi

if [ -s "$TEMP_SQL_FILE" ]; then
    sqlplus -s "$DB2_USER/$DB2_PASSWORD@$DB2_DB" <<EOF
    @$TEMP_SQL_FILE
    COMMIT;
    EXIT;
EOF
fi

# Clean up
rm "$TEMP_SQL_FILE"


"What is going wrong?" You are using Oracle 8i is probably what is wrong. It is 25 years old (and you may well be running it on hardware that is equally old).

yes but can't change that. any way to optimise?

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE statements for your table; the shell script you are using to perform the INSERT; the EXPLAIN PLAN for you INSERT. Without any details it is difficult (impossible?) to answer the question.

You absolutely must show us how you are doing the insert. We cannot guess your methodology. And I would ask why you can't use SQL Loader? An 8i client would provide this functionality and there's no reason why it wouldn't work for you.

hi @MT0 I have updated my question with the script.

This is easy - you are creating a separate SQL cursor and a separate database connection for every single row. You don't want to do that. Ever. The overhead is massive when it's for every row. You really do need to use SQL*Loader for this. Or you can use Python or Perl or any number of other options that make a single connection and a single insert but array bind values from a file.

Btw, you are also filling up the shared pool with unshareable cursors, which can cause the database to crash if it's bad enough. We don't create separate insert statement strings for every data value we want to work with. That is fine for a human entering in a few rows manually. It is not okay when you're bulk loading many thousands of rows, not to mention a half million.

Hello @PaulW thanks for your advice I will try to do accordingly. But the reason I had to resort to sql plus is because we could not connect to this database(8i) from Java app though 19c connects. This I still want to do if possible via Java/perl.
My next question is why was it so fast in 19c what's the main bottleneck in 8i. why I used multiple insert like for eg: INSERT INTO TABLE2 (USERID, SALARY, ZIP) VALUES ('user1', '5000', '10001');
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (USERID, SALARY, ZIP) VALUES ('user2', '6000', '10002'); is because I came to know that 8i does not support in a single insert like

continuing from above comment: INSERT INTO TABLE2 (USERID, SALARY, ZIP) VALUES ('user1', '5000', '10001'),
('user2', '6000', '10002'),
('user3', '7000', '10003');

@AlokKumar, you don't want to do that either - that shreds the shared pool. Learn to use proper bulk binding with shareable cursors. For your situation, you really do need to use a loading utility like SQL*Loader or write your own with any number of languages that have Oracle connectors. Don't use SQL Plus for this kind of task.

Try the following approach (steps are performed in one session):
Step 1:
ALTER SESSION SET skip_unusable_indexes = true;

Step 2: Disable indexes
ALTER INDEX index_name UNUSABLE;

Step 3: Do import
Step 4: Rebuild indexes
ALTER INDEX index_name REBUILD [ONLINE];


hi what is step 3 and also could you please explain what do these commands do.

Hello @AlokKumar The main idea is to disable indexes before inserting. You can try experimenting with step 3 (insert with or without a bulk). I would be grateful if you could share the results. Remember to complete all steps within one session.
